# What does this error mean: "TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I'm not sure what this error means:

> ```
> TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got slice(typing.List, <class 'int'>, None).
> ```

I am trying to confirm if a matrix has a given cell/index in it.
(In matrix `[[A, B, C], [D, E, F]]` does cell/index `[0, 2]` exist? Yes at C).

My input parameter is a list specifying the cell's index. I want to take the cell/list and modify it to check if it exists. Every time I try to touch the parameter list, it gives the error.

```
def in_matrix(matr: List[List:int], cell: List[int]) -> bool:
    b = cell.pop()
    a = cell.pop()
    print(a)
    print(b)
    for y in range(len(matr)):
        for x in range(len(matr[y])):
            if matr[a][b] == True:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

Answer (score 20):

This type `matr: List[List:int]` should be `matr: List[List[int]]` (in Python >= 3.9 you can even just use `matr: list[list[int]]`).

This means that `matr` is a list of integer lists, like:

```
matr = [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]
```